# Run simple Java class file with crontab

Tags: java, ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to run a simple java helloworld program with crontab.
I made the following java code:
helloworld.java:

```
class HelloWorld { 
     public static void main (String args[]) {
         System.out.println("Hello world");
   }
}
```

I then try to run this from a crontab in the following sequence:

1. `crontab -e`
2. At the end i insert this line `0,7,10,15,30,46,50,55,59 * * * * root /usr/bin/java /home/shivajividhale/cloudOccular/HelloWorld >/dev/null 2>&1`

However, I am not able to see the helloworld putput in the syslog. Is everything correct? How do I check if the class file is being executed or not. I tried printing the output to a text file with the time on it as well. But nothing is being done on the file.

Running the file normally `java HelloWorld` yields proper output. I also made sure the crontab ends with a new line.

I just want to get started with having a class file run by the crontab. Oher posts discuss about crontab running bash scripts, I just want to run just this simple program. I just want to print out Hello World along with the time to ensure program execution at the defined intervals. Any help?

Comment: how about if you redirect the output to a log file of your own? does that work?

Comment: Yes, good point, /dev/null just throws it away. He should do something like > /tmp/mylog.txt 2>&1

Comment: Well, that helped. Thanks :) However, I get an error: Could not find or load main class. I think it's something to do with the class path. But I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not provide a full path when trying to execute a class with "java". The "java" command expects to receive just the class name as an argument.

That's why this works properly:

> java HelloWorld

But this does not:

> /usr/bin/java /home/shivajividhale/cloudOccular/HelloWorld

To make the latter work, you need to provide just the class name, and additionally a "classpath" so that Java knows where to find that class. You can use the "-cp" option to provide the classpath.

Try this:

> /usr/bin/java -cp /home/shivajividhale/cloudOccular/ HelloWorld

Comment: Why do we have to provide classpath for running a java file from crontab but not when you try to execute normlly?

Comment: The current folder is in the classpath by default. Try running it "normally" but from a different folder and you'd need the classpath option as well.