# cron not running java program

Tags: java, cron

I am at directory location /home/oracle/naresh

Files InsertToTable.java, InsertToTable.class, runjava.sh, ojdbc6.jar are at /home/oracle/naresh directory location

InsertToTable.java is a file to insert data in to table. It makes use of ojdbc6.jar at run time. 
When running the below shell script independently, java will run successfully and data is inserted to table.

```
runjava.sh
-----------
#!/bin/bash
date >> /home/oracle/naresh/test.txt
export PATH=/home/oracle/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:$PATH
java -cp .:/home/oracle/naresh/ojdbc6.jar InsertToTable
exit 0
```

When running the same shell script from cron, java file is not running ..

To make sure, whether cron job kicked in or not , I am writing date value to a file, when cron job is run. -> writing data to file successfully
So, ideally thre are 2 tasks in shell, 1. writing to a file 2. execution of java

```
crontab:
----------
* * * * * /home/oracle/naresh/runjava.sh
```

cron not executing java file. 
Can some one tell me, how to execute java file with cron

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run simple Java class file with crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631213/run-simple-java-class-file-with-crontab)

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't compiling your java/jar file at all. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98914/how-to-use-crontab-for-a-java-file-in-linux) link will definitely guide to write any cronjob script properly including execution of Java/JAR files.